# Biblatex apa style do not seem to recognize inproceedings

Tags: biblatex, citing, cv

I am using this particular overleaf template ([A Customized CurVe CV template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv)) to edit my CV. I changed the citation style from "ieee" to "apa" in this particular line in the preamble:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{style=apa,sorting=ydnt,uniquename=init,defernumbers=true}{bibtex}
```

but when I compile the document, the publication headings change from "Conference Proceedings" to "Journal Article".

The following lines are in the publications.tex which I assume controls the output:

```
\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography}, title={Journal Articles}, type=article]

\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography}, title={Conference Proceedings}, type=inproceedings]

\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography},title={Books and Chapters},filter={booksandchapters}]
```

Is there a problem with the apa style that it does not recognize the inproceedings citation type?

Answer (score 1):

The biblatex-apa style maps the `@inproceedings` entries to either `@article` or `@incollection` depending on whether it has an editor. It does so following [the recommendation of APA](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/conference-proceeding-references) that conference proceedings should be formatted similarly.

You are probably better off using a different style if you wish to have a separate section for conference proceedings in your CV.